# Kafka concept for high availability at-least-one

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, high-availability

I have read some How To's regarding Kafka and how it works with topics, producers, consumers,  consumer groups etc but its not clear what you have to do to achieve no lost messages and that consumers in consumer-groups only read un-comitted messages. All examples are of the simplest kind and they give no guidance

**Scenario:**

Lets say I have a TopicA with 4 partitions P1-P4.
I have 2 consumers C1 and C2 that belongs to  consumer group CG1... What do I have to do when coding/setting up C1 and C2 so no messages will ever be lost i.e if C1 or C2 crashes/restarts they should start read unread messages (uncomitted) from P1-P4 in order they arrived to Kafka. Do I have to configure C1 and C2 to know about P1-P4 or is this done under the hood using for example  confluent-kafka-dotnet ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When C1 or C2 crashes (or be restarted) The alive consumer continue reading the partitions of the died consumer, when de consumer go alive again, the partitions are rebalanced again agains the consumers.

If your two (or N... all!) consumers crashes (or be restarted), when their go online again continue reading from the last point where they left it, without losing or repeating messages.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html

> Consumers in a consumer group share ownership of the partitions in the topics they subscribe to. When we add a new consumer to the group,
> it starts consuming messages from partitions previously consumed by
> another consumer. The same thing happens when a **consumer shuts down or
> crashes**; it leaves the group, and the partitions it used to consume
> will be consumed by one of the remaining consumers. Reassignment of
> partitions to consumers also happen when the topics the consumer group
> is consuming are modified (e.g., if an administrator adds new
> partitions).

https://medium.com/@jhansireddy007/how-to-parallelise-kafka-consumers-59c8b0bbc37a

> Q. What if consumer-B goes down? A. Kafka will do rebalancing and it
> would assign all the four partitions to consumer-A.

Answer (score 0):

> if C1 or C2 crashes/restarts they should start read unread messages

When a consumer crashes and comes back up it will start reading from the last read offset, so yes it will read uncommited messages only.

> (uncomitted) from P1-P4 in order they arrived to Kafka

Also one thing to consider when using more than 1 partition in a topic is that the messages may not be consumed in order.

You can read more about it here : [link](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2018-08-21-faq-apache-kafka-strict-ordering.html)

> Do I have to configure C1 and C2 to know about P1-P4 or is this done
> under the hood

We do not need to configure the consumers regarding the partition. It is taken care under the hood, where it tries to rebalance the partitions across all the consumers in a consumer group. If required we can also assign a particular partition to a topic.

More info at : [link](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/wiki/Consumer#partition-assignments)